# Build failed when upgrading to React Native 0.66 with M1 Apple Silicon (Precompile bridging header (arm64))

Tags: ios, react-native, apple-m1

I am currently trying to upgrade a 0.63 React Native project to 0.66, so that it is natively compatible with Apple Silicon (I try not to use Rosetta).

Up until now, I updated the package and added these lines to my Podfile:

```
installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
  config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
end
```

And I also tried adding `arm64` to the `Excluded Architectures`. However, no matter these steps, my build on XCode still fails at the `Compile Swift source files (arm64)` step, more specifically at the sub-step `Precompile bridging header (arm64)` with the following errors being reported:

```
<unknown>:0: error: module map file '/Users/tnguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-hcnyxhyoyudrligpcgxaqdhfyzgs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/InputMask/InputMask.modulemap' not found
<unknown>:0: error: module map file '/Users/tnguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-hcnyxhyoyudrligpcgxaqdhfyzgs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/YogaKit/YogaKit.modulemap' not found
<unknown>:0: error: module map file '/Users/tnguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-hcnyxhyoyudrligpcgxaqdhfyzgs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-text-input-mask/react_native_text_input_mask.modulemap' not found
/Users/tnguyen/my-project/packages/mobile/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/fmt/fmt.modulemap:1:8: error: redefinition of module 'fmt'
module fmt {
       ^
/Users/tnguyen/my-project/packages/mobile/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/fmt/Flipper-Fmt.modulemap:1:8: note: previously defined here
module fmt {
       ^
/Users/tnguyen/my-project/packages/mobile/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/folly/RCT-Folly.modulemap:1:8: error: redefinition of module 'folly'
module folly {
       ^
/Users/tnguyen/my-project/packages/mobile/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/folly/Flipper-Folly.modulemap:1:8: note: previously defined here
module folly {
       ^
/Users/tnguyen/my-project/packages/mobile/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/glog/glog.modulemap:1:8: error: redefinition of module 'glog'
module glog {
       ^
/Users/tnguyen/my-project/packages/mobile/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/glog/Flipper-Glog.modulemap:1:8: note: previously defined here
module glog {
       ^
3 errors generated.
<unknown>:0: error: failed to emit precompiled header '/Users/tnguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-hcnyxhyoyudrligpcgxaqdhfyzgs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/MyProject-Bridging-Header-swift_2LF8ULVDYSEYU-clang_2B4HUZEE1MPDX.pch' for bridging header '/Users/tnguyen/my-project/packages/mobile/ios/MyProject-Bridging-Header.h'
9 errors generated.
```

The first 3 lines and the last line are particularly highlighted, and so are the `redefinition of module` for `fmt`, `folly`, and `glog`.

I found similar issues to which no fix worked for my case, but I found nobody with exactly those same issues.
Does anyone have a recommendation on how to fix these?

Comment: When I get errors like this and cant find a solution to it I normally make a completely new clean project, see if its working and then copy and paste my way up till I have the old build running or discover where the error is since I did it step by step

Comment: This is something I would gladly do if the project I'm trying to upgrade wasn't really massive. But I've already tried starting a new project from scratch and it all went smoothly.